# I am not able to get any values to store in the array @AA

Tags: arrays, function, perl, module

It is getting the correct inputs and printing them inside the for loop but when I try to send it to a function module later or if I try to print it outside the for loop it is empty.
What do I need to change?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use lib "."; # This pragma include the current working directory 
use Mytools;


$inputfilename = shift @ARGV;
open (INFILE, $inputfilename) or die
            ("Error reading file $inputfilename: $! \n");

# Storing every line of the input file in array @file_array
while (<INFILE>){
        $file_array[ $#file_array + 1 ] = $_;
        
}
my $protein;
my @AA;
foreach $protein (@file_array)
{
@AA = Mytools::dnaToAA($protein);
print "The main AA\n",@AA;
}
print "The main array",@file_array;

my $header1 = "AA";
my $header2 = "DNA";
Mytools::printreport($header1, $header2, \@AA, \@file_array);
```

Comment: Use [strict](https://perldoc.pl/strict) and [warnings](https://perldoc.pl/warnings).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're overwriting the @AA in every iteration of the foreach loop.
Instead of

```perl
@AA = Mytools::dnaToAA($protein);
```

use

```perl
push @AA, Mytools::dnaToAA($protein);
```

See [push](https://perldoc.pl/push).

Next time, try to post runnable code (see [mre](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), i.e. avoid Mytools as they're irrelevant to the problem and make the code impossible to run for anyone else but you.